# How to create a hash of string to namespaced variable in freemarker?

Tags: dictionary, namespaces, variable-assignment, freemarker, variable-declaration

I am new to freemarker and want to achieve the below problem.

I have a some namespaced variables

#### Ex:

```
<@myNamespace.varA/>
<@myNamespace.varB/>
<@myNamespace.varC/>
```

I want to put it into a hash. There are three ways that I can think of, but I'm not sure if they are correct?

#### Method 1

```
<#assign MyHash = {
  "keyA" : <@myNamespace.varA/>,
  "keyB" : <@myNamespace.varB/>,
  "keyC" : <@myNamespace.varC/>
}>
```

#### Method 2

```
<#assign MyHash = {
  "keyA" : ${myNamespace.varA},
  "keyB" : ${myNamespace.varB},
  "keyC" : ${myNamespace.varC}
}>
```

#### Method 3

```
<#assign varA> <@myNamespace.varA/> </assign>
<#assign varB> <@myNamespace.varB/> </assign>
<#assign varC> <@myNamespace.varC/> </assign>

<#assign MyHash = {
  "keyA" : varA,
  "keyB" : varB,
  "keyC" : varC
}>
```

#### Method 4 ( keeping varA, varB, varC in local scope )

```
<#function getMyHash>
  <#local varA> <@myNamespace.varA/> </local>
  <#local varB> <@myNamespace.varB/> </local>
  <#local varC> <@myNamespace.varC/> </local>

  <#return {
    "keyA" : varA,
    "keyB" : varB,
    "keyC" : varC
  }>
</#function>
<#assign MyHash = getMyHash()/>
```

#### Note:

There might be other variables in the namespace that I don't want to put int the Hash
like

```
<@myNamespace.varD/>
<@myNamespace.varE/>
... etc
```

Comment: You usually build maps in java code (before) and not in freemarker

Comment: I get the namespaced values after passing a list to a transfrom ( in Java ).
This part needs to be handled in freemarker.

Comment: What's the type of the value of `myNamespace.varA`? You use it as if it was a macro or user defined directive, but is it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you want, like this:

```
<#function getMyHash>
  <#return {
    "keyA" : myNamespace.varA,
    "keyB" : myNamespace.varB,
    "keyC" : myNamespace.varC
  }>
</#function>
```

`<@.../>` is for calling macros (or other user defined directives), so it's not relevant. Unless, `myNamespace.varA` etc. are macros, and you wanted to put their output into that hash, but I guess that's not the case.